# Number not updating when button is clicked. Console also gives error that says "game" is not defined again. Any help is appreciated

Tags: javascript, html

very new to JS and programming in general. I was following a tutorial and hit another roadblock. I'm getting an error that says "game" is not defined alongside the number not updating when the button is clicked. I followed the tutorial closely and can't figure out where I went wrong mainly due to me being new at JS. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="sectionLeft">
    <center>
      <div class="scoreContainer unselectable">
        <span id="score">0</span> films<br>
        <span id="scorePerSecond">0</span> films per second</p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="clickerConatiner unselectable">
        <button onclick="game.addToScore(game.clickValue)">Produce Film</button>
      </div>
    </center>

    <div class="sectionFooter">
      <h5>Film Clicker</h5>
      <button onclick="resetGame();">Reset Game</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sectionRight" id="shopContainer">
    <table class="shopButton unselectable" onclick="buyCursor()">
      <tr>
        <td id="image"><img src="cursor.png"></td>
        <td id="nameAndCost">
          <p>Cursor</p>
          <p><span id="cursorCost">15</span> films</p>
        </td>
        <td id="amount"><span id="cursors">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="shopButton unselectable" onclick="buyCamera()">
      <tr>
        <td id="image"><img src="camera.png"></td>
        <td id="nameAndCost">
          <p>Camera</p>
          <p><span id="cameraCost">50</span> films</p>
        </td>
        <td id="amount"><span id="cameras">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="shopButton unselectable" onclick="buyLighting()">
      <tr>
        <td id="image"><img src="lighting.png"></td>
        <td id="nameAndCost">
          <p>Lighting</p>
          <p><span id="lightingCost">100</span> films</p>
        </td>
        <td id="amount"><span id="lighting">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    var game = {
      score: 0,
      totalScore: 0,
      totalClicks: 0,
      clickValue: 1,
      version: 0.000,

      addToScore: function(amount) {
        this.score += amount;
        this.totalScore += amount;
        display.updateScore();
      },

      getScorePerSecond: function() {
        var scorePerSecond = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < bulding.name.length; i++) {
          scorePerSecond += building.income[i] * building.count[i];
        }
        return scorePerSecond;
      }
    };

    var building = {
      name: [
        "Cursor",
        "Camera",
        "Lighting"
      ],
      image: [
        "cursor.png",
        "camera.png",
        "lighting.png"
      ],
      count: [0, 0, 0],
      income: [
        1,
        15,
        155
      ],
      cost: [
        15,
        50,
        100
      ],

      purchse: function(index) {
        if (game.score >= this.cost[index]) {
          game.score -= this.cost[index];
          this.count[index]++;
          this.cost[index] = Math.ceil(this.cost[index] * 1.10);
          display.updateScore();
          display.updateShop();
        }
      }
    };

    var display = {
      updateScore: function() {
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = game.score;
        document.getElementById("scorePerSecond").innerHTML = game.scorePerSecond;
        document.title = game.score + " films - Film Clicker";
      }

      updateShop: function() {
        document.getElementById("shopContainer").innerHTML = "";
        for (i = 0; i < building.name.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById('shopContainer').innerHTML += "<table class="
          shopButton unselectable " onclick="
          building.purchase('+i+')
          "><tr><td id="
          image "><img src=" + building.image[i] + "></td><td id="
          nameAndCost "><p>'+building.name[i]+'</p><p><span>'+building.cost[i]+'</span> films</p></td><td id="
          amount "><span>+'building.count'[i]+'</span></td></tr></table>";
        }
      }
    };

    windown.onload = function() {
      display.updateScore();
      disaply.updateShop();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to access the game object before it's created. Try defining the JS first.

Comment: Could you share which line the error is coming from?

Comment: Also, you have several typos. That might explain why `game` is having trouble being defined.

Comment: My advice would be to work with eventhandlers and functions rather than inline js and trying to access an object directly.

HTML, CSS and JS is interpreted top-down by the browser (although JS has some things called hoisting, but save that for later. Fact is, order matters). This means that at the moment you click your `Produce Film` button, game isn't defined due to being defined at a later stage than when assigned to the button.

Comment: This can be prevented by either re-ordering the JS to appear before any inline declarations in the HTML, or scoping the JS inside a jQuery document.ready scope or similar. Other than that, there are also various typos you'll need to go through.

Comment: @Rojo This is the line that the console says it's coming from "game.addToScore(game.clickValue)."

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors in your  `<script>`.

1. In `var display`, there should be a comma between `updateScore: ...` and `updateShop: ...` .
2. There are various mistakes in `updateShop`'s `for` loop body.

   1. You have double quotes inside double quotes, which is not permitted. Escape the inner ones with `\"` or use single quotes outside.
   2. Remember that you are concatenating  strings, so the opening and closing quotes should be consistent, and plus signs should be outside the quotes.

   it should be:

```js
document.getElementById('shopContainer').innerHTML += '<table class="shopButton unselectable" onclick="building.purchase('+i+')"><tr><td id="image"><img src="'+building.image[i]+'"></td><td id="nameAndCost"><p>'+building.name[i]+'</p><p><span>'+building.cost[i]+'</span> films</p></td><td id="amount"><span>'+building.count[i]+'</span></td></tr></table>'
```